# Run http.ListenAndServe() On Tests using stretchr/testify suite Stop Test From Proceed

Tags: go, gorilla, suite, testify

I'm trying to create integration tests for my REST API application which I made using [gorilla/mux](https://github.com/gorilla/mux), [gorm.io](https://gorm.io/) and [golang-migrate/v4](https://github.com/golang-migrate/migrate)

For the tests I'm using [testify](https://github.com/stretchr/testify).

My `SetupSuite()` in my `integration_Test.go` is like this:

```
func (s *ReceiptServiceTestSuite) SetupSuite() {
    s.Require().NoError(godotenv.Load("test.env"))
    s.Require().NoError(database.Connect())
    s.db = database.DB
    s.m = database.M

    router.HandleRequests()
}
```

And my `router.HandleRequests()` is like this:

```
func HandleRequests() {
    router := mux.NewRouter()
    router.Use(middleware)
    // lots of router.HandleFunc()
    
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", router)
}
```

The thing is: if I remove `router.HandleRequests()` from the `SetupSuite()`, all my database tests run normally, but if I try to `http.ListenAndServe()` the test workflow stop and nothing happens.

I believe that I should use goroutines with `router.HandleRequests()` so it can run parallel with the tests, I just can't figure it out how to do it.

For further information, here is the project [repository](https://github.com/RaphaSalomao/alura-challenge-backend), and I don't know if it is relevant, but I'm running two postgres instances using `docker-compose`, one for the project to run and another for the tests.

Comment: Run the root handler in a [test server](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http/httptest#Server) instead of http.ListenAndServe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out how to do it using go routines.

I read this [example](https://gobyexample.com/signals) which teaches how to deal with `os.Signals` using channels and I implemented it this way:

First, I made the following changes at the router:

```
func HandleRequests() {
    router := mux.NewRouter()
    router.Use(middleware)
    // lots of router.HandleFunc()
    
    go http.ListenAndServe(":8080", router)

    quit := make(chan os.Signal, 1)
    signal.Notify(quit, syscall.SIGINT, syscall.SIGTERM)

    <-quit

}
```

So now `http.ListenAndServe()` is running in a new thread. I believe that by a default behavior, it stops at the end of the program execution.

After `http.ListenAndServe()`, I created a `os.Signal` chanel which will listen to incomming signals from the system (SIGINT and SIGTERM), then the function will stop at `<-quit`, which will be wating for one signal to continue.

Then I fixed my `SetupSuite()` to run `router.HandleRequests()` in a goroutine:

```
func (s *ReceiptServiceTestSuite) SetupSuite() {
    s.Require().NoError(godotenv.Load("test.env"))
    s.Require().NoError(database.Connect())
    s.db = database.DB
    s.m = database.M

    go router.HandleRequests()
}
```

And at my `TearDownSuite()` I send a SIGTERM signal to the current process, wich will be listened by the `quit` channel I've created before at `router.HandleRequests()` and the function will proceed to terminate the program.

```
func (s *ReceiptServiceTestSuite) TearDownSuite() {
    // some database code 
    p, _ := os.FindProcess(os.Getpid())
    p.Signal(syscall.SIGINT)
}
```